# Target either selector on mouseover

Tags: jquery, selector, mouseover, target

I want to create a hover button when "body" or "p" is hover,
that means either one of them will trigger the hover event, how do you do that?

I assumed is something like this?

```
$("body")||$("p").mouseenter(function () {....});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery selector work like CSS selector, when you want multiple elements, you use comma :

```
$("body, p").mouseenter(function () {....});
```